# MySql search with two tables, one table for count only

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble with a MySQL query.

The query is pulling from two tables. Both tables contain data, but I only want a count(*) from the second table.

```sql
SELECT m.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cd_members_offers WHERE mo.mo_member_id = m.m_id) as mo_count 
FROM cd_members m, cd_members_offers mo 
/* these are variables and don't always exist */
WHERE (m.m_fname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_lname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_email LIKE '%Richie%')
AND (m.m_signupdate >= 20130807 AND m.m_signupdate <= 20130810)
AND m.m_add_state = 'QLD' 
AND (mo_count >= '2' AND mo_count <= '5') 
/* this is the end of the variables */
AND mo.mo_member_id = m.m_id 
ORDER BY m.m_id ASC
```

The /* quotes */ don't actually exist in the code. I just wanted to show how the query could potentially look if all variables are entered.

I had the issue at first where many duplicates would appear. I'm also quite confident that the mo_count >= is not the correct way to do it.

I'm still playing with the code and doing even more research, but if someone is able to save me some hours, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure not seeing your tables schema, sample data etc. but your query might look like this

```sql
SELECT m.*, COUNT(mo_member_id) mo_count 
  FROM cd_members m LEFT JOIN cd_members_offers mo 
    ON mo.mo_member_id = m.m_id 
 WHERE (m.m_fname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_lname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_email LIKE '%Richie%')
   AND m.m_signupdate >= '2013-08-07' AND m.m_signupdate <= '2013-08-10'
   AND m.m_add_state = 'QLD' 
 GROUP BY m.m_id
HAVING mo_count BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

Sample output:

```
| M_ID | M_FNAME | M_LNAME |          M_EMAIL |                  M_SIGNUPDATE | M_ADD_STATE | MO_COUNT |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1 |  Richie |  Richie |  richie@mail.com | August, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         QLD |        3 |
|    2 | Richie2 | Richie2 | richie2@mail.com | August, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 |         QLD |        0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3609/3)** demo

Comment: Thanks Peterm, your reply was super fast.

This is working quite well, apart from when users have a 0 mo_count, they are not displayed in the table.

I have never used the "HAVING" clause before, so I am very new in that regard.

Cheers for your help Peterm, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes I need to use the mo_count even when I need to display users with 0 count.

For example AND `(mo_count >= '0' AND mo_count <= '2')`

Would you still use the HAVING clause?

Comment: @user2663289 Yes you could do that. Updated sqlfiddle and the query once more to illustrate that

Comment: Thanks so much mate, your answer has helped me more than you can imagine. Both you and Sandeep have been so helpful.

I think I'm at the point now where I can figure this out on my own. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        SELECT m.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cd_members_offers mo WHERE mo.mo_member_id = m.m_id) as mo_count 
        FROM cd_members m
        /* these are variables and don't always exist */
        WHERE (m.m_fname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_lname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_email LIKE '%Richie%')
        AND (m.m_signupdate >= 20130807 AND m.m_signupdate <= 20130810)
        AND m.m_add_state = 'QLD' 
        AND (mo_count >= '2' AND mo_count <= '5') 
        /* this is the end of the variables */
        ORDER BY m.m_id ASC
```

Or can use the Group By with  having clause

```
        SELECT m.m_id, count(mo.mo_member_id)
        FROM cd_members m,cd_members_offers mo 
        /* these are variables and don't always exist */
        WHERE (m.m_fname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_lname LIKE '%Richie%' OR m.m_email LIKE '%Richie%')
        AND (m.m_signupdate >= 20130807 AND m.m_signupdate <= 20130810)
        AND m.m_add_state = 'QLD' 
        /* this is the end of the variables */
        AND mo.mo_member_id = m.m_id 
        Group by m.m_id
        having count(mo.mo_member_id) between 2 and 5
        ORDER BY m.m_id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I really like the method in your first one.

The remaining issue is mo_count:
AND (mo_count >= '2' AND mo_count <= '5')

Everything is working apart from that part of the sql. If I leave this line empty, the query works perfectly.

Thanks for your super fast response mate

Comment: Are you facing any problem with GroupBy Clause ? Otherwise for the first query you need to write outer query  to calcualte the condition `(mo_count >= '2' AND mo_count <= '5')`

Comment: Thanks so much Sandeep. You and Peterm have helped me more than enough. I'm at the point now where I'll have to spend sometime fine touching it to get it just right for me. I really appreciate it man!! Thank you :)